# Executing Ruby script in an Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can run the following commands in the console for my Rails application and import CSV file into my database.

```
require 'csv'

# row will be an array with the fields in the order they appear in the file
CSV.open('myfile.csv', 'r') do |row|
  # assuming the fields in the CSV file are in order npa, nxxFrom, nxxTo, trnk
  # create and save a Trunk model for each row
  Trunk.create!(:npa => row[0], :nxxFrom => row[1], :nxxTo => row[2], :trnk => row[3])
end
```

However I'd like to facilitate the process by just creating a script for it. The problem is I don't know how to write a script that is application specific. In order for the above commands to run, I need to launch console in the application folder by the following:

```
ruby script/console
```

So simply copy/pasting the commands into an .rb file and executing won't work.

Any help will always be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `script/runner "<code or filename here>`? to run the script?  The runner script executes the script in the give application context without having a console.

Comment: A better solution would be to have a rake task.

Comment: In 3.0+, use `rails runner path/to/script`.  Note: the path to your script is relative to your project root, not your working dir.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a rake task which inherits from environment. Place it into *lib/tasks/your_task.rake*:

```
task :your_task => :environment do
  # code goes here
end
```

Then run it using `rake your_task`. It can be called anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the rails environment in the script.

Try adding this at the top of you file:

```
RAILS_ENV = ARGV[0] || "production"
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), *%w[.. config environment])
# assumes script is placed one level below the root of the application
# second parameter is the relative path to the environment directory of your rails app
```