# How to run a script in a padrino context by passing the script path to padrino

Tags: ruby, padrino

How to run a script in a padrino context by passing the script path to padrino?
I see that similar feature is available in rails:
[Executing Ruby script in an Rails application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294596/executing-ruby-script-in-an-rails-application)

The padrino website: http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/development-commands
says this can be done by running

```
$ padrino r script/my_script.rb
```

But I get the error :

```
Could not find task "r".
```

Comment: All I read from [here][1] is `padrino rake ...`.    
  
[1]: http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/rake-tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat script/my_script.rb | padrino console
```

This worked for me